# How to get Column and row number of a calendar date

Tags: excel, calendar

How to get Column and row number of a calendar date in excel? 
Eg. Suppose my date is 26-May-17 so I should get rownumber=5 and column number=5

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to get. Are you looking to match the row and column number to the month of the date? Or are you trying to get the row and column number of where the address is in the Excel sheet?

Comment: Hi Anjali,  As I understand you are having dates from Jan1 in cell A1 till Jan 31 in cell A31 and similarly Feb1 in cell B1 till Feb 28 in cell b28, So this way you can use the below code.

Comment: @Anjali Where is your calender? can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are having dates from Jan1 in cell A1 till Jan 31 in cell A31 and similarly Feb1 in cell B1 till Feb 28 in cell b28, So this way you can use the below code.

```
Sub test()

MsgBox ActiveCell.Address(0, 0, xlR1C1)

End Sub
```